# sprintf blocks stm32 program

Tags: c, stm32, c-strings

I'm programming an STM32 microcontroller. In the code I'm just calling sprintf the way I did before and it worked then, but now it just freezes the entire program. What's the problem here?

```
char str[100]; 
sprintf(str, "TEMP_ADC: %d\n", 50);
```

I've included stdlib.h, stdio.h, math.h and string.h. The 100 char limit is more than enough.

I tried lighting LEDS above and below the `sprintf()` call and it's clear the program gets stuck on the `sprintf()`. I tried switching to `snprintf()` but it resulted in the same behaviour.

EDIT:

I noticed that `sprintf()` works when I use it before starting the DMA. If I use it after, the program freezes. Could it have something to do with casting an uint16_t array to uint32_t?

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  uint16_t values[4];

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

/* Configure the peripherals common clocks */
  PeriphCommonClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_MEMORYMAP_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();
  MX_RF_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  char str[100];
  sprintf(str, "TEMP_ADC: %d\n", 50);
  int size = (int)((ceil(log10(50))+1+11)*sizeof(char));
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1, str, size, 100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8, SET);

  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)values, 4);
  uint16_t temp = 0;


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
          HAL_Delay(1000);

        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      }
      /* USER CODE END 3 */
    }
```

Comment: You probably messed up something in another part of your code (maybe writing in some memory that doesn't belong to you). The code you show is 100% correct.

Comment: What you posted looks fine. Try doing a diff with the version that worked. Try commenting out as much of the code as possible. Post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky nowhere in the code do I even use the heap. You can see the snippet I provided doesn't even reference anything. That's where the program stops running

Comment: You can mess up things even without using the heap, for example with off by one errors writing into an array, buffer overflows, poor string management, etc. Who knows, we cannot see your code... As suggested by another comment, simplify your code until it works. Then you'll see what triggers the problem.

Comment: The code fragment presented in the question is not erroneous.  Nevertheless, it is a bit overblown.  `sprintf` is pretty heavyweight for a string that easily could be formatted manually.  The exact fragment shown could be more simply achieved with `char str[100] = "TEMP_ADC: 50\n";`.  Or if the real circumstances don't permit using an initializer, then `strcpy()` would still be an improvement over `sprintf()` for this particular case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'llk go out on a limb and guess that `50` is actually a variable in the real code, so it can't be hard-coded.

Comment: I considered that, @Barmar, and you may well be right. But then I'd have to DV the question, so I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @JohnBollinger We ask for a *minimal* example. If the variable is not relevant to the problem, omitting it is reasonable. Just because you can simplify the sample code even further doesn't make it DV-worthy.

Comment: @Barmar, if I were going to DV because the code could be *simplified* then I would have DV'ed already.  My DV would be because the code presented was not representative of the code that produces the error.

Comment: I guess you did not initialize `str` right before you call `sprintf` like your code shows here? Because it is possible, that you did some sort of stack-smashing beforehand and try to de-reference a pointer to null or a pointer to an oom-address.  That would be my best guess, tough i am not familiar with the controller itself.

Comment: @Barmar is correct, first the problem came up when I was using an uint16_t variable with a value of 50 and for the sake of simplicity I hardcoded 50 there for testing. (both behave the same in the program)

Comment: @led I am calling the function after the initialization.

Comment: Does it work when you use `sprintf(str, "a", 2);` ? Does it work when you use the solution @JohnBollinger proposed: `str[5] = "HELP";` ?

Comment: There's simply no way to answer the question from the little information you've provided. The problem is almost certainly somewhere else in the program. When you cause undefined behavior, the symptoms can be in completely unrelated parts of the code.

Comment: @led, `str` is an array, not a pointer.  it is not necessary to initialize it before writing into it.

Comment: @Barmar is it possible that the incorrect cast in the edit causes the problem?

Comment: If `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA()` expects a `uint32_t[4]` array, and you pass a pointer to a `uint16_t[4]` array, you'll probably get an out-of-bounds array access, which causes problems.

Comment: Casting the pointer type silences the compiler warning, but it doesn't change the size of the array to be compatible.

Comment: @Barmar changed it to ```uint32_t``` and removed the cast, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Simplify and update your call.

Comment: @pts It is as simple as it gets. Currently there is only the STM32 automatic initialization code, ```HAL_ADC_Start_DMA()``` and the ```sprintf()``` part. I need to know what makes it so that starting the ADC prevents ```sprintf()``` or ```snprintf()``` from being used.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Yeah Comments leave little room for explanation. So first things first: `str` in itself is without a doubt a pointer. If you just de-reference it with `*str` you get the first entry of the array. It may be constant, but still a pointer. Second: I should have been more precise: Initializing is not the problem. The possible problem i wanted to point out is writing over the variable that stores the pointer value. This way you might de-reference a pointer to 0.

Comment: @epicMan123. Can you try to increase the size of `values[x]`? I can not look into all the functions you use there, but something like `values[8]` or `values[16]` might work. Do not touch the last argument of `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA` at the same time. The only way you might have messed with `str` that i can see here is when you are accessing `values` in `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA()`. So testing the bounds there could lead you to a solution.

Comment: @led, Declared as `char str[100];`, variable `str` is without doubt *an array*.  Like any array, it is automatically *converted* to a pointer where it appears in most expressions, including `*str`.  Among the ways you can distinguish is via the `sizeof` operator, one of the few contexts where arrays are not automatically converted to pointers.  **In no way are arrays pointers.**  And I have no idea what you mean by "writing over the variable that stores the pointer".  There is no "variable storing" a pointer, just the results of the aforementioned automatic conversions to pointer.

Comment: Overall, @led, no, there is no issue at all with the OP's first code snippet.  It is not only completely fine, but also highly idiomatic, exactly as is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Man maybe i am not smart enough for this and i really do not want to fight about the C spec, you probably know this stuff better than i do. But please tell me what it is, that is passed as the first argument for the `sprintf()` function in his code. And yes the code is fine NOW. But OP states, that the problem arises when using `start_DMA` before `sprintf()`. And `start_DMA`  also accesses part of the stack or am i wrong here?

Comment: @led, arguments in a function-call expression are not among the very few exceptions to automatic array-to-pointer conversion.  Thus, it is a pointer to the first element of array `str` -- the result of such an automatic conversion -- that is passed as the first argument to the `sprintf` calls in the code fragments presently appearing in this question.  Together, that element and the following 99 provide more than enough space to hold the output of that particular `sprintf` call.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Ok thanks for the confirmation. But that still leaves my other question: Is it possible, that the address, `str` points to at the moment it is passed into `sprintf()`, is zero, because it was previously overwritten by the dma function?